# Make div only display once on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a div with a class (.popUp) that fades in on my home page over the rest of the content. I only want this div to appear on the first load of the page. If the user was to revisit that page I don't want the div to show again.

I would like to use cookies and have read a few posts regarding this but they don't seem to be exactly what i'm after?

Really hoping someone can help me out with this.

Thanks for your time.

Not sure if you need this but -

JS:

```
$(".popUp").fadeIn(1000);
$("#popUpBtn").click(function(){
$(".popUp").fadeOut(500);
});
```

CSS:

```
.popUp {
display:none;
position:fixed;
z-index:99;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:url(../images/popUpBack.png);
}
```

Comment: cookies are the way to go for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: `$(function() { 
  if ( !$.cookie("seen")) {
    $(".popUp").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#popUpBtn").click(function(){
      $(".popUp").fadeOut(500);}
    });
    $.cookie("seen", 1); 
  }
});`